# Searchview open on right button click

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

i am new in IOS 7 .can anybody help me how can i remove title and open UISearchBar in UINavigationBar when i click on right bar button.see image below.

[image]

thank you in advance.